# Python concurrency isn't concurrent

Tags: python, asynchronous

My employer uses Box. It's API is very slow. Fortunately our files are largely static. Nightly I can iterate (recursively) over Box folders and store the URLs in a local file. Using the local file during the day substantially improves the performance of our scripts that read from and write to Box.
Starting the recursive search (spider) at level 0 includes folders we don't care about. So we have a named list of starting points from level 1. I'd like to recursively search them in parallel.

When I observe the code below (via logging/print statements I have hidden) it does not seem to search under the starting points in parallel. In instead searches the entire tree under starting point 1, then the tree under starting point 2, etc.

My question is: why does the code below not execute the spider method concurrently for each item in `for storage_dict, starting_point in zip(cache_dict_list, starting_dir_list)`?

```
import asyncio
 
@asyncio.coroutine
def spider(storage_dict, dir_list):
    """Recursive storage of Box information in storage_dict."""
    storage_dict = {"key": "value"}

cache_dict_list = [dict() for x in starting_dir_list]
task_list = list()

async def main():
    for storage_dict, starting_point in zip(cache_dict_list, starting_dir_list):
        task_list.append(asyncio.create_task(spider(storage_dict, [starting_point])))
    await asyncio.gather(*task_list)

asyncio.run(main())

total_dict = dict()
total_dict.update([cache_dict.update(x) for x in cache_dict_list])
```

Comment: Could you specify what the question is?

Comment: I don't understand question. And I don't see any recursion.

Comment: And I don't understand `storage_dict = {"key": "value"}`. It can't put/replace data in `storage_dict` and in `cache_dict_list`. It only replace value in local variable `storage_dict`. it would need `storage_dict["key"] = "value"`

Comment: The spider function has recursion (yield from spider(...)), I just left it out to simplify.

A work-around I came up with was to replace spider() with subprocess.getstatusoutput(), which is less elegant but avoids the unpickleable error thrown when trying to use multiprocessing with a yield from.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is basically that async isn't multithreading (more on threading later). Async basically queues up tasks which are executed by the event loop. So when you `await asyncio.gather(*task_list)` you are basically saying "put all these tasks in the queue(ish) and wait until they are done." If you used more async and await statements within `spider()` you could split it up more in the queue, but ultimately it would still take about as long since only one item in the queue will be processed at a time.

Then, we have `threading`. This (kinda) allows for concurrency. However, it isn't much better if you are resource-capped, because cpython uses a global interpreter lock (GIL). The GIL means that basically, a single python process can only utilize one core at a time, which avoids issues that can happen when multiple cores try to access and modify data at the same time.

However, if you want true concurrency, you can use the `multiprocessing` module. How you implement this probably depends on exactly how you want to get and store your data (in order to avoid the issues with multiple cores that are the reason for the GIL), but basically it will allow you to use multiple cores concurrently.